# Is it possible to debunk Intel Management Engine conspiracy theories using a data usage monitor device?

Tags: privacy, hardware, backdoor, cpu, intel

If there would be any backdoor in recent Intel CPU's, then it should send and receive data secretly.

Isn't it possible to easily debunk this conspiracy theory by implementing a third physical device between the computer and the router to find out if there's a difference between the amount of data transferred as reported inside the operating system and the actual amount of data that the third device in the middle counts?

Comment: How do you know that it always transfers data and not just when requested? You could leave your house unlocked, then put a camera behind the door for two hours and see that nobody entered. That doesn't mean that there isn't a literal open door for anyone to waltz into and take all your stuff.

Comment: You have a lot of assumptions in your question, especially in how and when the "backdoor" is accessed. If you remove those assumptions, you are left with the much simpler question: "can't we monitor traffic to detect backdoors?" and the answer is quite obviously "yes, if monitoring is set up on the same channel as the backdoor". Your question is making assumptions about the channel and the type of monitoring required for this backdoor.

Comment: Guys, you're not wrong, but I think it's a legitimate question and we should treat it as such instead of posting comments and downvoting. If you have an answer that includes "your question makes wrong assumptions, in reality X could happen", sure, then that is your answer. Doesn't make it a badly researched or unclear question.